# Requirejs : Non amd library

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I have a script.js included in the website of my customer. This customer uses requirejs but he append script.js at the end of the body without explicitly using requirejs to load it.

In script.js i have libraries that are amd compatible and other not. The problem is that requirejs automatically load library which are amd. And i can't access them in my own library which is not amd compatible.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Not really sure what the question is. Make your library AMD compatible?

Comment: Well it would be great. Unfortunately i can't at this time.

Comment: This question is much too vague as currently written. There are ways to make an app that uses RequireJS work with code that does not use RequireJS but the methods that can be used are dictated by the details of the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RequireJs has the ability to ["shim"](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) configuration. In your requirejs configuration call, use the following (from the requirejs page). Backbone in this case is not a requirejs module and used as an example.

```
requirejs.config({
  shim: {
    'backbone': {
        //These script dependencies should be loaded before loading
        //backbone.js
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],

        //Once loaded, use the global 'Backbone' as the
        //module value.
        exports: 'Backbone'
    }
```

})

You can then use Backbone just like any other module:

```
define(['backbone'], function (Backbone) {
   return Backbone.Model.extend({});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i have no access to the requirejs config of my customer. He just append ath the end of the body our script.js